# Magento 2 - build a unique id for the term's checkbox for payment methods using vault

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3, checkbox, terms-and-conditions

For payment methods using vault, the id generated for term's checkbox is duplicated as the payment method name is same.

```
/**
         * build a unique id for the term checkbox
         *
         * @param {Object} context - the ko context
         * @param {Number} agreementId
         */
        getCheckboxId: function (context, agreementId) {
            var paymentMethodName = '',
                paymentMethodRenderer = context.$parents[1];

            // corresponding payment method fetched from parent context
            if (paymentMethodRenderer) {
                // item looks like this: {title: "Check / Money order", method: "checkmo"}
                paymentMethodName = paymentMethodRenderer.item ?
                  paymentMethodRenderer.item.method : '';
            }

            return 'agreement_' + paymentMethodName + '_' + agreementId;
        },
```

I see this code in checkout-agreements.js. However, in my case, cybersource vault method results in same paymentMethodName, leading it to duplication if there is more than one stored payment/ saved card.

I need help in coding the id attribute of term's checkbox dynamically here:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="required-entry"
                       data-bind="attr: {
                                    'id': $parent.getCheckboxId($parentContext, agreementId),
                                    'name': 'agreement[' + agreementId + ']',
                                    'value': agreementId
                                    }"/>
```

and its respective 'for' attribute of label.

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve the issue in this way.

I added $index property of $parentContext. However in this case the parent is 3 levels up.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="required-entry"
                       data-bind="attr: {
                                    'id': $parentContext.$parentContext.$parentContext.$index() + '_' + $parent.getCheckboxId($parentContext, agreementId),
                                    'name': 'agreement[' + agreementId + ']',
                                    'value': agreementId
                                    }"/>
```

I added $index as prefix to existing id. One can add as suffix also.

`$parentContext.$parentContext.$parentContext.$index()` same is added for 'for' attribute of respective label.

Comment: This solved a bug for me. Thanks for this. I did switch it around so the ID becomes `$parent.getCheckboxId($parentContext, agreementId) + '_' + $parentContext.$parentContext.$parentContext.$index()`. This way, the ID doesn’t start with a number, making easier it to process as a selector.